# How can I create a div in jQuery that I can scroll left to right in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am creating a movie search engine. So far when I type in a movie into my input I receive a list of movies as shown in the screenshot below.

[The way my movies are shown. I have to scroll down to see more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMd4G.jpg)

Instead I want my images to be represented similar to how they are in google.

[The way google shows its movies. You have to scroll right to see more, but the page remains static, only the movies change as you scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfDki.jpg)

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need code to help you. We can't debug what we don't see.

Comment: Please include the HTML, CSS and the JS code corresponding to the search engine result display.

Comment: you don't need any javascript for this

Comment: `<div style='width:200px;overflow-x:scroll'><div style='width:2000px'>content</div></div>`

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with css but if the situation require JQuery you can do it like below

```
$('#search-container').append(
  $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "movie")
    .addClass("new-movie")
    .css({"width": "1000px", "overflow-x": "auto"})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 document.getElementById("content").style.overflowX = "scroll";
document.getElementById("content").style.width = "200px";
```

Try this in your js.